# Unity Plugin that contains androidx library functions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, androidx, android-unity-plugin

I  created an Android plugin for unity to handle some native jobs and it works fine on my device, until I wanted to add "WorkManager" class to handle some background jobs and I received following error:

```
java.Land.NoClassDefFoundError:
androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest$builder
```

I think the problem is that the androidx library does not exist at Runtime. my question is: How to add androidx support library to Unity3D?

Comment: post your gradle.

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha05'
}

Answer (score 0):

Because using `implementation` , You can't use their Internal library's component.

Still You want to use, You need to manually import that library in Unity.

Download aar file from [here](https://maven.google.com/android/arch/work/work-runtime/1.0.0-alpha06/work-runtime-1.0.0-alpha06.aar).
and import into unity project.

Comment: I'll give it a try... meanwhile how can I include runtime library directly into my plugin instead of importing another aar into my unity?

Comment: I tried I. Now error changed to "java.Land.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx.work.impl.model.WorkSpec$1"

Comment: ok remove that aar file and write `compile` instead of `implementation`.

Comment: I change it to compile and despite the "obsolete error" it gave, nothing happened. Is there any way to include runtime library into my final plugin file?

Comment: "obsolete error" is not a error. Bro once you have to try it.

Comment: ;))). I tried it and I get the java.Land.NoClassDefFoundError:
androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest$builder error again.

Comment: I just tried but run into this: https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/145

Comment: @Gabor I used Jar resolver but It shows "Resolution Succeeded" but nothing happens

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Of course that's the case in general unless you do something.

Comment: I mean the problem still exists, and Google's Jar resolver "Thinks" that "Resolution Succeeded" but it is not!